# Feel dizzy while doing crunches

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, workout, abdominals, home-exercise

I have recently started doing exercise for my abs. I exercise in following pattern

Do 40 Jumping jacks

25 High knees

then

15 basic crunches

15 bicycle crunches

10 alternate heel touches

I have started with small numbers,keep each crunch-exercise between 8 to 15, but I start feeling dizzy while doing crunches.. I want to do more exercise but I simply can't. After doing this minimum exercise that i mentioned above I am unable to do any more exercise, I have to take rest almost 1 hour to get rid of nausea. What I am doing wrong? what should I do else to get my body in shape? I have a big tummy and I want to make it flat.

**Note:** I take complete rest, almost 8-10 hours a day so there is no sleep deprivation issue.

Comment: Make sure you're doing these very slowly and focused. Slow and steady, focusing on contraction and holding it for a second is better than hammering out reps. Also I'd see a doctor as you could be putting undue pressure on intestines or spine or something if you feel nauseous.. that could also be lactic acid accumulate too from all the reps

Answer (score 1):

First off, have you seen your doctor about this? This could be something innocuous like low blood sugar or not being in the best shape to start with. It could also be something considerably more serious. And is it specifically the crunches that cause the dizziness? Do you get the same dizziness if you do a standing crunch (standing upright, hands behind your head, and curling down as if you were doing a crunch on the floor)? Are you breathing throughout the crunch or are you holding your breath perhaps?

If you haven't done a lot of abdominal exercise, honestly, it might simply be that you're not in very good shape. Crunches are harder than people give them credit for. If you can't see a doctor, I recommend cutting your number of crunches a little lower for a week or so, say only do 5, or do them from a standing position (assuming those don't make you dizzy). It may feel like you're not getting much exercise, but you're teaching your body to accept it. And make sure that you're breathing as you do it. Don't hold your breath.

Lastly, it's possible that you're dealing with [Benign Paroxysmal Positional Vertigo](http://abstractfitness.ca/blog/vertigo-when-exercising-feeling-of-dizziness/), a disorder that happens from excessive deposits in the eardrum, although that commonly manifests itself with any positioning where your head is not upright, so you probably would be running into it in other situations. If it is BPPV, one option is to switch to other exercises. Planks are recommended in the link above. Getting up to holding it for 60 seconds (and again, don't stop breathing during it) takes most people a bit. Another is treatment by a doctor, and we're back to my initial point. It's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: thanks for the response,No i haven't seen doctor as I wanted to know if it is normal or if it happens while a person starts exercising..Yes specifically crunches are causing dizziness, I do other exercises like i mentioned above; jumping jacks, high  knees, touching my feet in standing position etc and it is fine I don't feel dizzy while doing these exercises, and I don't hold my breath ... I just started the exercise but this nausea making me want to quit because it feels terrible afterwards, like I said I have to lie down quietly for at least 1 hour.

Comment: [It's not uncommon](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071212095530AAV2soj). I've added another possibility to the answer.

Comment: Benign paroxysmal positional vertigo is a condition that would show its symptoms during other (head) motions too. I consider this *diagnosis* wrong and unnecessary here. Switching exercises would be no solution as well, as every neurologist could treat the condition. I would definitely see a doctor, especially for an ultrasonography of your cervical arteries.

Comment: Now that you have an account (and rep of 101 presumably due to membership on other sites), you should be able to comment. Yeah, the BPPV bit was not very well-researched by me, but it was brought up in a few places for crunches. I totally missed that it's readily treatable.

Comment: I don't think it's a "diagnosis", as @SeanDuggan stated "it's possible". Yes, it may be an outlier and easily treatable, but he didn't categorically state "You have X". He just mentioned it as something to consider.