# Weight put on due to stress eating

Tags: weight-loss, bodyweight

Due to some personal issues I have been stress eating/binge eating for last 7- 8 months and have put on 11 kg weight. I was 64kg a few months back (which I was trying to drop to 59) and now I am around 75kg (height 5'4, female). Now I am extremely tense due to this weight gain but I am not able to adopt any healthy routine, in fact i have totally forgotten what was my routine before. I really need your support and guidance.

What should I do to stop binge eating, and to lose some weight?

I can do moderate cardio like walking, jumping jacks etc but cannot join gym or do machines.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Start doing light exercises then gradually do more intense exercises. Do what you feel comfortable doing and what you know you will stay motivated doing. Also, avoid eating too many sugary foods, otherwise it will be extremely difficult to lose any weight. On another note, is [this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27594/feel-dizzy-while-doing-crunches) your old routine?

Comment: I mean, I hate to state the obvious, but the answer to *what should I do to stop binge eating* is not to workout more, it is to stop overeating. This is really a nutrition question/psychological question. Some tips to stop binge eating, though: plan out your meals (and don't skip them), drink water more often, clean the junk food out of your home, and make sure you sleep more.

Comment: Just to second what C.Lange said, the best thing to do for stress and stress related issues (i.e. binge eating) is to seek out someone specifically to help with those issues, a psychologist / therapist of some sort. It's honestly one of the best things you can do for yourself. People always talk about taking care of their physical self (weight loss, eating healthy, etc), but very rarely their psychological self, and often that is far more important.

Answer (score 2):

So this is a two part answer.

Part one: **Stop binge eating**

To stop doing this you need need to understand why you binge eat when you do it. If the problem is that, when you feel stress or discomfort you go to food to feel better, you need to find something to replace the food. Find something else that makes you feel better that you can resort to which isn't an unhealthy habbit.

Part two: **Losing weight**

To lose weight you can start by simply walking. 30 minutes a day, then 1 hour a day. This combined with more control over your diet will give great results. If you want to step it up a notch you can do multiple other forms of cardio like cycling or swimming. You can also start doing some light strength training with things you can do at home like pushups, situps, planks, inverted rows, squats, you name it.

I hope it helps! Feel free to ask questions.